# Can I restrict generic type parameters to require the Default_Value aspect?

Tags: generics, ada

Ada 2012 comes with a `Default_Value` aspect for types. Is there any way to restrict generic type parameters to require that they have a default value (or is there even a general way to check for any aspects?)

basically my question is if the following example can be made safe. currently gnat throws a warning

> main.adb:6:03: warning: variable "Var" is read but never assigned [-gnatwv

when i don't define MyFloat with `with Default_Value => 10.0`.

```
-- main.adb
with MyProc;

procedure test is
  type MyFloat is new Float with Default_Value => 10.0;
  package P is new MyProc (MyFloat);
  Var : P.Bla;
  Var2 : MyFloat := P.Stuff (Var);
begin
  null;
end test;

-- MyProc.ads
generic
  type MyTypeWithDefault is private;
package MyProc is
  type Bla is tagged private;
  function Stuff (Self : Bla) return MyTypeWithDefault;
private
  type Bla is tagged record
    Data : MyTypeWithDefault;
  end record;
end MyProc;

-- MyProc.adb
package body MyProc is
  function Stuff (Self : Bla) return MyTypeWithDefault is
  begin
    return Self.Data;
  end Stuff;
end MyProc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in pre Ada 2012 style:

```
generic
  type MyTypeWithDefault is private;
  Default_Value : in MyTypeWithDefault;
package MyProc is
  type Bla is tagged private;
  function Stuff (Self : Bla) return MyTypeWithDefault;
private
  type Bla is tagged record
    Data : MyTypeWithDefault:= Default_Value;
  end record;
end MyProc;
```

But you do raise a good point; there should be some way to specify the new aspects in the formal parameters of a generic.